# A Different Approach to Prove Non UFD for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{4k+1}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In case When $D=4k+1>1$, then I want to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ is not a UFD

Had it been UFD, It would mean it is integrally closed. However it is not integrally closed. So we reach a contradiction.

But I would like to stick with a basic definition. That is I am trying to factor $4k \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ in two distinct ways.

I considered the factorisation $4k=2 \times 2k=(1+\sqrt{4k+1})(-1+\sqrt{4k+1}))$ and I am trying to show these two factorisations are distinct.
However I am not sure if $2$ is irreducible or not. Would like some guidance here.

And this general case seems very difficult to deal with. Anyone suggestions how to deal such cases.

Comment: Use the norm, $N(a+b\sqrt{D}) = a^2-Db^2$. If $2$ is reducible, then  there must be some element of norm $2$ or $-2$. But $a^2-Db^2=\pm 2$ has no integer solutions: since $D\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, looking at this modulo $4$ you have that $a^2\equiv 0,1\pmod{4}$, $b^2\equiv 0,1\pmod{4}$, so $a^2-Db^2\equiv 0$, $1$, or $3\pmod{4}$.

Comment: If $x+y\sqrt{4k+1}\mid 2,$ then $x^2-(4k+1)y^2\mid 4.$ If $x^2+(4k+1)y^2=\pm4,$ then $x+y\sqrt{4k+1}$ is a unit times $2.$ So you need $x^2-(4k+1)y^2=\pm2.$ Show this is impossible by looking modulo $4.$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Do you mean we get $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)=2 \operatorname{mod} 4$ doesn't have solutions because both $x,y$ have same parity because RHS is even but looking at the factorisation it will be $0$ modulo $4$>.

Comment: No. Where do you get that? I mean exactly what I said: the map $N\colon\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $N(a+b\sqrt{D}) = a^2-Db^2$ is a norm. It is multiplicative, and $a+b\sqrt{D}$ is a unit if and only if its norm is $1$ or $-1$. If $2=rs$ for some $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$, then $N(r)N(s)=N(2)=4$, and neither $N(r)$ nor $N(s)$ are $\pm 1$. So they are equal to $2$ or $-2$. But $a^2-Db^2$ cannot equal $2$ or $-2$, which can be verified by considering the value of $a^2-Db^2$ modulo $4$. What I wrote. I said nothing about $a$ and $b$ having the same parity. Who said they have?

Comment: (I am telling you how to verify that $2$ is irreducible.)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I am assuming that if $2$ was reducible then I have norm of a factor is $2$, then in that case I will get a contradiction because if $N(x+y\sqrt{D}$=\pm 2$, then I will get $x^2-y^2(4k+1)=2$ and here I get a contradiction.

Comment: Isn't that what I wrote? If $2$ were reducible, there would be a factor of norm $2$ or $-2$, but no element has norm $2$ or $-2$. So $2$ is irreducible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Yes, I was just explaining how we can prove no element has norm 2,. I just saw reduce modulo $4$ and conclude